# What's my best choice?

Tags: desktop-environments

I need to install the latest version of Ubuntu on a 32 bit machine, but it seems that 20.04 has no 32 bit version.
What's my best choice?
Thanks

Comment: Opinion based answers are off-topic on ask ubuntu. You would be better doing some research and asking a specific question about a specific supported official release/flavour of ubuntu.

Comment: Related: [How can I run Ubuntu 20.04 on 32-bit devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330415/how-can-i-run-ubuntu-20-04-on-32-bit-devices)

Comment: Install Debian directly.

Comment: You have to confirm that your CPU is 32-bit only. It is very likely that it is 64-bit capable. If it is so - then install Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS from [this link](https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/bionic/ubuntu-mate-18.04-desktop-i386.iso) and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 32-bit LTS (long term support) is Ubuntu 18.04. It will be supported until April 2023, so this would buy you another year and a half. If you need more time, you'll have to opt for another OS. Debian still offers 32-bit support and Ubuntu is based on Debian so it could prove a logical choice.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this response. Would you please give me the link to its ISO image?

Comment: Please note no Ubuntu Desktop ISO/image was produced for i386 in 18.04; only *flavors* of Ubuntu provided i386 images and they're now all EOL (but ISOs can be found).  Yes Ubuntu Desktop is supported; but you need to build the install yourself (or upgrade from a prior release, ie. to build netboot installer was available).   FYI:  Two *flavors* (Lubuntu, Xubuntu) kept producing ISOs into the *disco* (19.04) cycle but most i386  builds was turned off once *disco* reached EOL so 18.04 was the last supported.